# Use presentModalViewController from a subView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I wanna use the `presentModalViewController` method from a subview, but it's not working for me
here is my code:

The subview:

```
-(IBAction) PressMoyensEs {
    MoyensEstimatifsViewController *MoyE = [[MoyensEstimatifsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoyensEstimatifsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:MoyE animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your `self.parentViewController`? It's likely to be `nil`, as it is in many case, and thus your code is failing silently.

And, have you tried just `[self presentModalViewController:MoyE animated:YES];`? It's less 'correct', but if working, would already exclude some causes of failure.

Comment: I fixed it, U were right, the self.parentviewController was nil, i resolved the problem by adding an id parameter that contains the parentcontroller, thanks again